# how to enter valid date in database for separate date month year

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a registration form in my project on which I used three dropdownlists to enter day, month and year. In this date added to dropdownlist by codebehind method:

```
private void Add_Date()
{
    ddl_dat.Items.Add(new ListItem("-Date-", "-1"));
    for (int j = 0; j < 31; j++)
    {
        var newOption = new ListItem("" + (j + 1).ToString(), j.ToString());
        ddl_dat.Items.Add(newOption);
    }
}
```

And I add 12 months manually in month dropdownlist. I want user don't able to enter 29 feb or 31 april.
I done this by appling check before submitting the form:

```
if (ddl_year.SelectedIndex != -1 && ddl_dat.SelectedIndex != -1 && ddl_mon.SelectedIndex != 0)
{
    if (ddl_mon.SelectedIndex == 2 && ddl_dat.SelectedIndex >= 28)
    {
        lbl_alert.Text = Convert.ToInt32(ddl_dat.SelectedValue)+ 1 + " Febuary Doesn't Exist";
    }
}
```

Same method for all other months . But I don't think this is the correct method to solve this problem. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wanted: DateTime.TryNew(year, month, day) or DateTime.IsValidDate(year, month, day)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467967/wanted-datetime-trynewyear-month-day-or-datetime-isvaliddateyear-month-d)

Comment: That is one way to do this. Don't forget about months with only 30 days though, and also leap years - where February does actually have 29 days. Using a calendar control is also a good option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply this check before submitting form:

```
string str = ddl_dat.SelectedValue + "/" + ddl_mon.SelectedValue + "/"
                + ddl_year.SelectedValue;
DateTime dt;
if(!DateTime.TryParse(str, out dt))
    // Invalid date - Show error
else
    // Use date from dt here
```

If date is invalid `TryParse` will return false. Else you can use the resulting date from `dt` variable for further operation.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is ASP.NET, you can use `UpdatePanel` to dynamically fill the contents of Date combobox on-the-fly through AJAX. You could then use `DateTime.DaysInMonth()` to find out the exact number of days in a month. You should update your Date combobox on both month and year dropdown's `SelectedIndexChanged`. This way your user won't be able to select incorrect dates in the first place, so no need to handle any errors.

Alternately there is Javascript calendar available in JQuery that could make your life easier.

Comment: Thanks for answering dotnet. your answer is good. but ajax is not working on my server so i want to do it by coding.

Answer (score 1):

[DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ch92fbc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should help you.

```
DateTime dateValue;
string dateString = ddl_year.SelectedValue + "-" + ddl_mon.SelectedValue + "-" + ddl_dat.SelectedValue;
if (! DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dateValue)) {
    //Error...
}
```

Comment: kryssthanel Onr error is in your answer you don't declare datevalue